# AWS - Why does AWS EC2 t2.micro instance show 8GB RAM?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I'm trying to figure out what size instance I need for my webapp, but am confused by this:
[image: ubuntu]

A t2.micro only has 1 gig of memory, but yet this looks like I have 8.

There's no swap usage so how much memory does my instance actually have?

Thanks.

Answer (score 5):

I think you got the answer, but to confirm that its a disk try this command

```
df -h
```

you will see that   `Filesystem Size Used Avail Use% Mounted on`

2. To confirm your memory try this command.

   > free -h

Answer (score 4):

what you see in the screenshot is disk size, the EBS storage, not the RAM
the default disk size is 8 GB and is mounted under / path

Comment: Great observation! :)